# how to know the previous length of a column after altering that

Tags: sql, oracle, flashback

I have altered the size of a column in Oracle , and now i want to get the prev size  of that column, so is there anyway we can get the prev size of that column.

Thanks.

Comment: The teaching is, changes to the physical data model should be subject to governance, so scripted and managed in a source control repository like any other piece of code.

Answer (score 4):

You may use `flashback` on `user_tab_columns` :

```
SQL> conn <your_schema>
SQL> create table tab( str varchar2(20) );
SQL> alter table tab modify str VARCHAR2(30);
SQL> conn / as sysdba
SQL> grant flashback on user_tab_columns to <your_schema>;
SQL> conn <your_schema>
SQL> select *
  from user_tab_columns
 as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' minute c 
 where c.column_name = 'STR'
   and c.table_name = 'TAB'; 
-- the period depends on your latency of issuing the commands
-- "'1' minute" may be replaced with "'10' second" as an example.
```

Comment: So to perform flashback operation we need to first get the permission from dba right? Because i can not connect as sysdba, I am using the schema only.

Comment: @Danish sure, you need to consult your DBA.